# Nginx with http/https - Http seemed redirected to https all the time

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, godaddy, uwsgi

I've this really weird behaviour with my ubuntu 10.04 / nginx 1.2.3 server.
Basically I changed the SSL certificates this morning.
And ever since it has been behaving weirdly on all apps.
Godaddy is reporting that HTTPS/SSL setup is correct.

When I try a page it still works correctly when I'm using HTTPS.
But when I try using HTTP nginx reports error :

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

After looking around on google for hours, I've tried different setup (while originaly my setup was working correctly for longtime, I just renewed certificates)

I kindof found a half solution by adding this to my config :

error_page 497 $request_uri;

The realllly weird thing is that when I use this setup :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name john.johnrocks.eu;

    access_log /home/john/envs/john_prod/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/john/envs/john_prod/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/john/envs/john_prod/john.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }

    location  /media  {
        alias   /home/john/envs/john_prod/johntab/www;
    }

    location  /adminmedia  {
        alias   /home/john/envs/john_prod/johntab/www/adminmedia;
    }
}
```

I still have the same error when using HTTP (while nothing is setup for HTTPS here)??

I'm getting crazy on this !

**Update

Even with this config :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  john.johnrocks.eu;

    access_log  /home/john/envs/john_prod/nginx.access.log;

    location / {
        root   /home/john/envs/john_prod/johntab/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

I get error 400 (The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port) on everything I try to load ..

Comment: Basically it seems that all traffic is redirect to the 443 port whether I try seeing a page with http or https
So all my apps are working correctly in https
but when I try http I get error 400 "the plain http request was sent to https port"
The weird thing is that I didn't change my setup
All was working fine before
I just renewed the ssl certificates from godaddy
Any idea ??????

Comment: Now I have change my vhost file many times with suggestions from internet
doesn't change a thing
I halve fixed it with
error_page 497 $request_uri;
so it's a trick that catch the error and return what's requested instead
now my webpage is completely weird
it loads, but all the additional resources are loaded, but with error 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was.
The problem comes from how nginx loads the vhosts configurations.
If you look at nginx.conf, you will find this line

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

So this loads all the "vhosts" into the main nginx.conf in a random order.
So what happend is that the error was somewhere else, in another vhost .. and it was making all the vhosts fail basically (no error was detected by nginx, it was not an error per se but a bad configuration).

So I removed all the sites-enabled vhosts, and put them back one by one, reloading nginx and testing the site each time until I got them all right and then voilà

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you fixed it. Why don't you select your answer as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the 400 error, but if you had an 301 (permanent) redirect in your previous config, the browser might still have stored this redirect in the cache and doesn't check the original. Maybe purging your caches might help.